# Using a bitmap as transparency with a threshold

Tags: texturing, shader-nodes

Here is an example of using a gradient to control the threshold on transparency on Z-axis as explained in [this video](https://youtu.be/7QwE7sB80GQ?t=193).

[image]

I can animate the location of the colors in the gradient:

[image]

But I want to use a grayscale bitmap as a pattern to follow for the transition. This image could work as a "clock" transition.

[image]

Here is a primitive attempt with curves:

[image]

I can not animate the RGB curves node. Here is a manual animation moving the curves for each frame:

[image]

And here is another manual animation using this other texture:

[image]

[image]

**How can I combine a bitmap with a gradient to control the threshold?**

Comment: i am really not sure what effect you wanna have. Can u show a yt video or gif how your wished effect should look like?

Comment: I added some animations :)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can add a ColorRamp and animate the slider.

[image]

Comment: Oh. It was simpler than I thought. Thanks.

Comment: Happy to help, good luck with your project ;)

Comment: +1 nice with that clock image…and even 3D‼️

Comment: @Chris Thanks, gotta make it fun for myself :)

Comment: That’s why it looks so good!!!